# Set subdomain as environemt variable in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, variables, environment

I want to get the subdomain-string and set an environment variable in the htaccess file to that value:

```
SetEnvIf Host TEST\.mywebsite\.lvh\.me MAGE_RUN_CODE=TEST
```

This is working, but I would need to add such a line for every subdomain. I want this working for every subdomain.

So if I visit test.mywebsite.lvh.me, MAGE_RUN_CODE should be set to test.
If I visit subdomain2.mywebsite.lvh.me, MAGE_RUN_CODE should be set to subdomain2.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^([^\.]*)\.mywebsite\.lvh\.me$ MAGE_RUN_CODE=$1
```

Here a little explaination:

```
^ starts the expression
$ end the expression
() This defines a group and is the tricky part. It stores the value in $1, 
   more groups would store it in $2, $3...
```